# Expand API functionally with separate modules

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js project, that will function as a basic API. Now, I'd like to extend the functionality of this API via modules. This modules should be able to expose additional methods to the API and I'd like to somehow keep them in separate git repos. This modules should be recognized with as less configuration as possible (best case: simply adding it to the dependencies in `package.json`).

As you may have guessed, my node.js knowledge is yet somewhat limited. In Symfony, where I come from, this would be accomplished by services. Now, there is this [node.js service-container module](https://github.com/linkshare/service-container), but I don't know if that's the "node-way" to go.

Comment: I am assuming that you are talking about a REST API. In that case, what you are talking about can be achieved with [express](http://expressjs.com/). An express app can be composed of sub-apps.

Comment: Can you point me to a more concrete example? Also a solution without a framework would be interesting.

Comment: I would love to, but it is very hard to give any concrete examples before you ask a more concrete question! Does "basic API" refer to a RESTful API? Do you have an example to show what "additional methods" could be exposed from a different repository? Have you read the express documentation that I linked you to? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work? You might find the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it

First: Create a configuration file to hold your API endpoint to handler mapping (and your app config in general)

```
config.modules = [
{
  moduleLocation: "/path/to/my/module1.js",
  apiPath: "/api/myAPI1"
},
{
  moduleLocation: "/path/to/my/module2.js",
  apiPath: "/api/myAPI2"
}
];
config.port = 8080;
module.exports = config;
```

Second, In your node main app, use express to dynamically mount the mappings in config

```
var config = require('./config');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.listen(config.port, function() {
 console.log("server starting on port " + config.port);
});

for(var module in config.modules){
  app.use(module.apiPath, require(module.moduleLocation));
}
```

Your module files (module1.js and module2.js) should look like this:
    var router = express.Router();

```
// invoked for any requested passed to this router
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
   // .. some logic here .. like any other middleware
  next();
});
```

This way, in order to extend your API you only have to add the handling module to your app, add the mapping to the config file, and restart your node app. This is the minimum config I can think of :)